# Postgres - recommend free visual modelling tool with reverse engineering feature

Tags: postgresql, reverse-engineering, modeling

Please recommend free visual modelling tool with reverse engineering feature if such exists.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you'd better define your reverse engineering needs. What results/output are you looking for?

Comment: I just need a readable diagram which I can print

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been happy with [SchemaSpy](http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/) for visual modelling. It produces handy reports on the DB structure and relationships, good structural diagrams, and more. See [these sample pages](http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/sample/) from a simple demo database, including [this structural diagram](http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/sample/relationships.html) . It also has the handy ability to produce smaller structural diagrams specific to each table, showing relationships with that table by one or two degrees of separation.

SchemaSpy works great with PostgreSQL. Just make sure you put the path to the PgJDBC driver jar on the SchemaSpy command line as `-dp /path/to/PgJDBC.jar`.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Please accept the answer with the tick :-)